# Laravel Stop SSL Redirect on FORM Helper

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-form

I have a web form in Laravel that is behind an ip. Example:

```
127.0.0.1/posts/create
```

With a simple form helper:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/posts','files'=>'true')) }}
    @include('posts._form')

    {!! Form::submit('Create Post', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When I inspect the html, https is added to the url. How can I stop this?

Comment: What is your APP_URL set to in .env?

Comment: APP_URL=http://xx.xx.xx.123 - the app address

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, my nginx had the HTTPS variable set on. Laravel apparently reads that variables and adds the protocol + host_name to all redirect actions.